# How to open workbook on a certain row without using Workbook_Open?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a working macro that creates a new workbook, writes to it, and emails it to a client.

The workbook opens on the first row of the workbook, and the client needs to scroll down to find the data they need.  I would like the Excel file to open in the middle row of the file.

The workbook cannot contain macros due to security reasons.  Thus writing code on the `Workbook_Open()` method to go to a certain row is not feasible.

Comment: Are you saving the book before sending? I'm guessing not as this seems too obvious of a solution

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not saving. I know that saving will open the workbook on the 'selected' cell just before the save though.

Comment: Did you find any answer useful?
Please post feedack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have your VBA code select a given `Range` and make it visible on screen prior to sending, it should be the selected range and visible when opening directly from the attachment.
As intended in the OP, you do not need your workbook to contain any VBA code.

I did this with the code below to create the workbook
Then I manually selected *Send by email* (it should be irrelevant if this is done via VBA), sent it to myself, and opened it from the attachment.

```
Sub create_wb_select_range()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks.Add
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = wb.Sheets.Add(After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count))
    Dim wsname As String
    wsname = "MySheet"
    ws.Name = wsname
    Dim rngname As String
    rngname = "J68"
    ws.Range(rngname).Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Without SELECT I suppose there is theoretically another option: 1) unzip xlsx file, 2) modify xml file of last modified sheet: line "<selection sqref="K34" activeCell="K34"/>" (my last modified cell was K34 in my sample unzipped excel file), there are some solutions for these operations, but it seems to be overcomplicated and select is better

Comment: I will try this tomorrow and provide an update, thanks!

Comment: @RafałB. - As you said, it may work, but it seems an overkill.

Comment: @Aiyuni - Did you have a chance of testing the proposed solution?